# Is it worthwhile having less locked code but more lock calls?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety

I have some pieces of code in a multi-threaded environment that access a shared variable. Obviously I need to `lock` for these accesses, but my question is whether I **save** or **create additional overhead** by locking the variable for a short amount of time to get a value, unlocking, doing some things with what I retrieved, then re-locking to modify the data structure that I just unlocked.

Obviously for very expensive operations that can be done outside of a lock, you would benefit by not locking that segment. What about, for example, the following, where the operations being done are relatively inexpensive (creating a `new object` and an `if statement`):

Less threaded:

```
Value v;
lock (values)
{
   v = values.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Thing == someValue);
   if (v == null)
   {
      v = new Value { Thing = someValue };
      values.Add(v);
   }
}
```

More threaded:

```
Value v;
lock (values)
{
   v = values.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Thing == someValue);
}


if (v == null)
{
   v = new Value { Thing = someValue };
   lock(values)
   {
      values.Add(v);
   }
}
```

Both solutions are thread safe and both are quite readable (IMHO), but it would be nice to build into my habits the more efficient of the two, if there is even a slight difference between the two.

Comment: Well what do your performance benchmarks show, for your specific application? Do your benchmarks actually show that this piece of code is significant at all? If not, go with the simplest code and don't worry about it. (As well as the bug noted by Hans, of course :)

Comment: That's a bug.  The values collection may well have the "thing" added by another thread between the locks.  These kind of bugs are *nasty* since they strike so infrequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second will, potentially, buy you extra performance, but realistically, it will only be an issue if the `Value` constructor is relatively expensive.

In the second case, you're avoiding the `lock` over the null check (which is very fast), but also while constructing the `Value` instance.  This could, potentially, be a significant improvement in performance.

That being said, this is *not thread safe*.  A second thread could add the value to the code between the two lock statements.  As such, I'd recommend the first approach (realizing that you'd always have to lock `values` for any other operation that uses that collection).

If this lookup is a common one, a better approach might be to use `ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>` instead, with `Thing` as the key.  You could then use the [GetOrAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676.aspx) method to safely add or retrieve the value.

Comment: Yikes! You are correct that it is not thread safe. That's what I get for throwing together an example quickly.

But thanks, basically what I get from that is that it's only potentially worthwhile if the constructor is doing something expensive. That works.

Comment: @Dan In general, separating out locking can provide benefits - especially if there's expensive code that can be separated out.  But it makes the amount of risk go up as well...

Answer (score 0):

The second case is not thread safe because while a thread is checking if v is null, another thread could have inserted a value  equal to someValue (as you name it)